# Invert text color according to plane color

Tags: color, text-object

Im just starting learning using blender, and I have some little problem. I have some plane and text object, and here the color of the plane object is randomly generated. [image]

The problem here is that the "Level 10" text is indeed visible but Ive wanted to know if there was some way to be sure that I wont be generating a color that is too close of the text, and thus I thought that the simplest solution would be to simply invert the color of text in relation to that plane color. Is there anyway to do this ? Thank you very much!

Comment: is it rendered using Eevee?

Comment: Yes Im using Eevee @lemon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do a color invert like this:

[image]

But it depends on the pattern and the colors you have whether it is easy to read or not...

sometimes maybe brightness and contrast is the better choice...

[image]